# mod_ssl not compiling with apache2

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-ssl

**SOLVED**

Resolved, but it was a strange issue. I check config.log, as suggested by Capsule and found the following line:

```
configure:14368: checking whether to enable mod_ssl
configure:16123: result: no
```

I was wondering why it wasn't installing ssl when I had clearly asked it to. Then I found the configuration command it had parsed in:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --enable-so--enable-cgi--enable-info--enable-rewrite--enable-speling--enable-usertrack--enable-deflate --enable-ssl--enable-mime-magic
```

*Notice the lack of spaces?* I had entered the command with each directive in a new line so it was missing spaces, and the arguments were not being correctly passed.

And now it works as expected!

---

Apache build ( 2.2.1 ):

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache \
    --enable-so \
    --enable-cgi    \
    --enable-info   \
    --enable-rewrite    \
    --enable-speling    \
    --enable-usertrack  \
    --enable-deflate \
    --enable-ssl    \
    --enable-mime-magic
```

When I try to configure ssl, i get the following as I try to restart apache

```
Syntax error on line 56 of /usr/local/apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
Invalid command 'SSLPassPhraseDialog', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Here're the list of compiledin modules **( SSL is missing )**

```
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 authn_file_module (static)
 authn_default_module (static)
 authz_host_module (static)
 authz_groupfile_module (static)
 authz_user_module (static)
 authz_default_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (static)
 include_module (static)
 filter_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 env_module (static)
 setenvif_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mime_module (static)
 status_module (static)
 autoindex_module (static)
 asis_module (static)
 cgi_module (static)
 negotiation_module (static)
 dir_module (static)
 actions_module (static)
 userdir_module (static)
 alias_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 php5_module (shared)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! How did you type the commands on several lines? Would be interesting to know why it misses most of the spaces.

Comment: Just like I posted it, I copied pasted that from a file to the server, and to here.

Comment: Well, this is really strange. I could understand several spaces mess things up but you have only one after "--enable-so" and it disappears. I guess your shell or ssh client didn't like the paste opeartion then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if ./configure doesn't yell about something missing when checking for openssl librairies. It probably didn't compile right, hence the module not listed.

You can also have a look at config.log